# different meanings of 'number'

Tags: meaning, differences

My motherlanguage is german, in german there are several words for slightly different meanings of the term **number**, or do I just not know their english counterparts?

**Examples:**

German term **Ziffer**:

Ziffer is a single numeral digit (In deceimal numberation 0-9)
It's, so to say, a numeral letter.

German term **Zahl**:

This is, what I guess, the german counterpart to number.
It's 1-(n) numeral digits wich displays an value that you can increment, operate with and wich tells you the value of something.

German term **Nummer**

A number, it sounds like **number** without a **b** but a longer **m**, is something like an index, wich you may can, but maybe not, increment.
It doesn't necessarily holds an value, but refers to something. Like every page on a book as a number, also the license plate on your car has a number on it. Even if there are letters, not only numeral digits, its a **Nummer**. 
You may can, but in most cases it does not provide logic output to do arithmetic operations on these numbers.

**The Question now:**

Are there english counterparts to these meanings in of the german terms?

Comment: Are you asking about programming terms?

Comment: No, in daily usage.

Comment: Can you maybe provide photos of each?

Comment: As you recognize above, *digit* is the English counterpart to *Ziffer*; I believe it means almost exactly the same thing (it also means a finger, but that's not likely to be confused with the *Ziffer* meaning.) But we use *number* for both *Zahl* and *Nummer*.

Comment: @curiosdannii a picture of what please? That doesn't makes sense to me.

Comment: @Peter Shor, isn't digit a single symbol in a word, or number?

Comment: @Sempie: No; the standard meaning is that a *letter* is a single symbol in a word, and a *digit* is a single symbol in a number. Some computer programmers may use digit for both (since we don't actually have a word that encompasses both, and *alphanumeric character* is rather long), but that use is not familiar to most English speakers.

Comment: I am a programmer, so that may be why I thought a digit is also a letter. Thanks for that correction. Also, your comment answers my question. Please post it as a Answer, so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Sempie: I think the last word 'nummer' is more akin to 'identifier' in more formal context, but in daily usage, as you mentioned, it's the same 'number', even if there are alphabetical characters, e.g., license plate number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *Ziffer*, use *digit* or *numeral*.  It is a single symbol for a value, 0-9. Since digit also means a single finger or toe, the image of counting on one's fingers is a good way to remember this.

For *Zahl*, use *number*. That is one or more digits, a value that can be used to compute or to list in increments. With the ordering function, English uses *ordinal number*: first, second, third. *Cardinal number* distinguishes absolute value (one, two, three) from ordinal number.

For *Nummer*, also use *number*.  *Telephone number* and *license number* are common terms.  A license number or a telephone number can be expressed by all numerals, or mixed numerals and alphabet letters. The telephone company or the licensor may use a  sequence of these numbers to catalogue the owners, but the numbers are not used for computation.

Thank you for this interesting question. I have always admired the German language for its precision.